# Mistake in proof for $\varphi_Z (u) = \Pi_{i=1}^n \varphi_{X_i} (u)$ for $Z= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$?

Tags: probability

**Problem:** Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be independent random variables, $X_i \colon 
(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, P) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}), i=1, \ldots , n$.
Let $Z = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$. Show by induction that the characteristic function for $Z$ is the product of the characteristic function for the $X_i$'s:
$$ \varphi_Z (u) = \Pi_{i=1}^n \varphi_{X_i} (u).$$
**Instructor's solution which I believe to be wrong:**
For $N=2$ it follows from theorem 15.2 in Jacod and Protter. Assume it's true for $Z_{n-1}$. Then since $Z_n = Z_{n-1} + X_n$ and since all $X_i$'s are independent, we especially have that $Z_{n-1} = h((X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}))$ for $h \colon \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}, h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i$ is independent from $X_n$ by theorem 10.1.(c) in Jacod and Protter. ...

---

From what I can see, it is assumed that because the $X_i$'s are mutually independent, my instructor says that then $(X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1})$ and $X_n$ are independent, which would be false. Am I right, or am I missing something?

---

**My own solution which I'm unsure about:**
For $N=2$ it follows from theorem 15.2. Assume true for $n=N$. Then
\begin{align*}
    \varphi_{Z_{N+1}} (u) 
    &= E ( e^{i \langle u, Z_{N+1} \rangle }) \\\\
    &= E ( \Pi_{j=1}^{N+1} e^{i \langle u, X_j \rangle} ) \\\\
&\stackrel{10.1.(e)}{=} \Pi_{j=1}^{N+1} \varphi_{X_j}(u)
\end{align*}
where we for 10.1.(e) use that $\mathbb{C}$ is a metric space and $f(z)=e^{i \langle u,z\rangle}$ is bounded and continuous.

Comment: Your instructor is right actually. If you take two measurable functions $f$ and $g$, $n$ random variables $X_i$ which are mutually independent, and $k \in \{2,\dots,n\}$, then $f(X_1,\dots, X_{k-1})$ and $g(X_k\dots,X_n)$ are independent, and that's true in particular for when $k=n$ and $f$ and $g$ are the identity function like in this case.

Comment: How does one see this? Is there a place in Jacod and Protter or somewhere else you could reference me to?

Comment: Just found a PDF of Jacod and Protter: I would say the closest there would be Theorem $10.1.(c)$ if you allow $f$ and $g$ to go to $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of just $\mathbb{R}$. The proof doesn't really change *a fortiori*. Then it's a matter of seeing $(X_1,\dots, X_{k-1})$ and $(X_k\dots,X_n)$ as your $X$ and $Y$, but of course here that intermediate step of understanding why $X$ and $Y$ are independent is precisely your issue here! Kinda going in circles here, sorry. Try working with the definition of independence of random variables to figure that last piece out.

Comment: I see. I think I tried to go through it and it seems to work out in the end by some similar considerations to those made in corollary 10.1 - it seems one ends up concluding equality of the measures based on the uniqueness of measures theorem known from measure theory, or alternatively similarly to what is done in the uniqueness part in Fubini's theorem but in higher dimensions. Anyhow, I believe it works out in the end. It seems quite an incredible result that mutual independence of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and $Y$ implies independence of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $Y$, but, great for us, I guess :)